# Novel where a girl, Sre, hatches a dragon, Blue, to defend her from an innkeeper

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons

I need help to find a book I read years ago on an adult website.

The author had a group on Facebook and kept us updated on her stories. Eventually she got a publisher and even showed us what she planned for the cover. (A girl and a dragon)

About the book:

(I forgot a lot since I think I read it between 2010 to 2012, it was an ongoing series).

But it starts of with an orphan girl who works in an inn/pub. Her name was Sre. I think the innkeeper tries to rape her one night and there's this dragon egg in the shed that hatches at that moment and ends up defending her against the innkeeper. I think it kills him then she goes on the run.

She eventually builds a life for herself, paired with her dragon, I think his name was Blue. She meets a dragonrider with black eyes and is half alien or something like that. But they eventually marry. She has a dragon crest/tattoo, which could mean she's royalty.

Comment: Found an author named Cly Novak, with *The Dragon Tamer*, bones of the story seem to match, but it doesn't look like anything else ever came of it.  The book itself doesn't seem to be online at all.

Comment: @Radhil I think you've found it. It ticks a lot of OP's boxes - the main character is an orphan called S’re, and she has power over dragons and a strange tattoo. One of the Amazon reviewers mentions a "dragon/alien cross over" and the author's website (https://clynovak.wixsite.com/clytopia/books) definitely mentions "alien races" on the planet.

Answer (score 21):

It looks like this book was [*The Dragon Tamer*, by Cly Novak](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23871238-the-dragon-tamer).

This answer is largely based on a [public forum post](https://forum.xnxx.com/threads/the-dragon-tamer.135831/) (NSFW, possible trigger warning too) that carries elements similar to what you describe.

- Female protaganist named S’re, orphan, works at an inn for food/shelter.
- Soldiers with black eyes and dragons. Mostly hostile, but one, Roscrow, starts bonding.
- Innkeeper is an ass.
- Definite rape elements.

There does appear to have been a full novel published around this story, and Amazon has a listing for it, but no eBook format is currently available for sale.  The author does not appear to have updated [their website](https://clynovak.wixsite.com/clytopia) since the printing, I cannot find any other primary internet presence for the author, and I can find no other books bearing the author's name.